# Display calculation in MVC Core View

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, percentage

I'm trying to display the result of a percentage calculation in a view.
Round and Score are coming from a local database, I want to count the number of rounds recorded, add up the values stored in Score, then output result as a percentage. I hope that makes sense!

Currently I have a few values stored in the database but the result I am getting all the time is zero. Values from the database do not seem to be getting into the calculation method.

Thanks so much in advance!

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult CalcPercent()
    {
        PracticeViewModel pvm = new PracticeViewModel();
        
        var rounds = _context.Practices3.Select(r => r.Round).Count();
        var scores = _context.Practices3.Sum(s => s.Score);
        pvm.Percentage = scores / (rounds * 10) * 100;

        return View(pvm);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Practice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public double Round { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PracticeViewModel
{
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model EmailAndPDF_Test.Models.PracticeViewModel

<p> @Model.Percentage</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error   public INT Percentage { get; set; }; you have to change it to public DOUBLE Percentage { get; set; };

Why instead var rounds = _context.Practices3.Select(r => r.Round).Count();
you don't use  _context.Practices3.Count(); Maybe you mean _context.Practices3.Where(r => r.Round>0).Count();?

Try instead of       pvm.Percentage = scores / (rounds * 10) * 100; to use
pvm.Percentage =  Math.Round((scores / (rounds * 10)) * 100,3);